# Finding duplicates matching particular conditions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Below is the sample data I'm working on.

```
sender  receiver    date    id
salman  akhtar  20161201    1111
akhtar  salman  20161201    1112
nabeel  ahmed   20161201    1113
salman  akhtar  20161201    1114
salman  akhtar  20161202    1115
nabeel  ahmed   20161202    1116
ahmed   nabeel  20161202    1117
nabeel  ahmed   20161202    1118
nabeel  ahmed   20161202    1119
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to find duplicate entries based on the condition, same sender and same receiver within the same date.

For this, I wrote the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

print 'Script for Finding duplicate entries\n'

path = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
print 'Loading file. Please wait...'

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(path+'.xlsx')

print 'File loaded successfully.\n'
sheet = raw_input('Enter Sheet Name: ')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet)

df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(['sender', 'receiver','date'],keep=False)

df_dup = df.loc[df['is_duplicated'] == True]

print 'Found Below Duplicates'
print df_dup

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df_dup.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()

print 'File created successfully.'
```

Now, I want to incorporate `fuzzywuzzy` as well because the current code only return EXACT duplicates and I want all POSSIBLE duplicate rows based on the said conditions.

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> fuzz_ratio = 50
>>> df_rem = df[~df.duplicated(['sender', 'receiver','date'],keep=False)]
>>> df_possible_dup = pd.merge(df_rem, df, on='date', suffixes=['', '_j'])
>>> df_possible_dup.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x['sender'], x['sender_j']) >= 50 and x['id'] != x['id_j'], axis=1)
```

I don't know your exact requirements, but probably you want to check if sender or receiver are matching exactly and other part is possible matching. Then you can use your custom function:

```
def worker(x, fuzz_ratio):
    if x['id'] != x['id_j']:
        return False

    if x['sender'] == x['sender_j'] and fuzz.ratio(x['receiver'], x['receiver_j']) > fuzz_ratio:
        return True

    if x['receiver'] == x['receiver_j'] and fuzz.ratio(x['sender'], x['sender_j']) > fuzz_ratio:
        return True

    return False

>>> df_possible_dup.apply(lambda x: worker(x, fuzz_ratio))
```